# How to create a d3 bar chart using array value

Tags: d3.js

I want to create an bar chart with using array values. I don't want to use any csv or tsv file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should look up approaches and attempt it first before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some research you could have done before asking,

D3 Bar chart examples:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Also check out C3, and this example:
http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar.html